# php server.php start sleep after some time

Tags: php, socket.io, server

i am using this command to run **php  server.php start**. but after sometime it automatically stop responding. here is my sample code. i am running penny auction script through this.

```
<?php
use Workerman\Worker;
use Workerman\WebServer;
use Workerman\Autoloader;
use PHPSocketIO\SocketIO;

// composer autoload
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
include __DIR__ . '/src/autoload.php';  

$io = new SocketIO(2020);


$io->on('connection', function($socket){
      }
```

anyone have idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Is there a specific time at which the script stops running?

Comment: @JezEmery nope if i check the service it is running but not responding